# Are Service Fabric Partition Identifiers persistent?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

In Service Fabric we can get a **Partition Identifier** from a Service Context.

The [docs doesn't say much](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.servicecontext.partitionid?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Fabric.ServiceContext.PartitionId);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=azure-dotnet) about this property. :-(

I'm wondering whether this identifier is persistent for **stateful services**, so that it is assigned the same value every time the stateful service partition is started.

I've tested this by creating a reliable service on the local development cluster. After stopping and restarting the cluster the same partition identifiers were indeed reported.

Can I trust that this will always be the case?

If not, what would cause it to change?